# Updating a pandas dataframe column based on another column / TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: pandas, dataframe, lambda, types

I'm updating a column with another column's value if it's value is zero

```
dft = pd.DataFrame(
                        np.array([
                                    ['MAXESSUS', 0], ['BLOOMBERG', 'CORP'], ['BROKER_TEC', 'GOVT'], ['MAXESSUS', 0]
                                ]), columns=['market', 'rbc_security_type1']
                  )
dft

      market    rbc_security_type1
0   MAXESSUS    0
1   BLOOMBERG   CORP
2   BROKER_TEC  GOVT
3   MAXESSUS    0
```

This is my function

```
dft['rbc_security_type1'].apply(
                                    lambda col_value: col_value['rbc_security_type1'] if col_value['rbc_security_type1'] == 0 
                                                                                    else col_value['rbc_security_type1']
                               )
```

> The desired output

```
dft


      market    rbc_security_type1
0   MAXESSUS    MAXESSUS
1   BLOOMBERG   CORP
2   BROKER_TEC  GOVT
3   MAXESSUS    MAXESSUS
```

> I'm getting this error:
>   TypeError: string indices must be integers
>
> Is the issue that rbc_security_type1 has both strings and integers and
>   a conversion of the column type needs to be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need compare by string `0` because numeric was converted to strings and then use `loc`, [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) or [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
#if mixed values - numeric with strings compare by numeric
#mask = dft['rbc_security_type1'] == 0
mask = dft['rbc_security_type1'] == '0'
dft.loc[mask, 'rbc_security_type1'] = dft['market']
```

---

```
dft['rbc_security_type1'] = np.where(mask, dft['market'], dft['rbc_security_type1'])
```

---

```
dft['rbc_security_type1'] = dft['rbc_security_type1'].mask(mask, dft['market'])

print (dft)
       market rbc_security_type1
0    MAXESSUS           MAXESSUS
1   BLOOMBERG               CORP
2  BROKER_TEC               GOVT
3    MAXESSUS           MAXESSUS
```

**Detail**: For check if numeric with strings:

```
print (dft['rbc_security_type1'].apply(type))
0    <class 'str'>
1    <class 'str'>
2    <class 'str'>
3    <class 'str'>
Name: rbc_security_type1, dtype: object
```